# how to connect the python program with the database?

Tags: python, database, window

i'm a beginner for python. I have a project about access system which use python coding and connected to the database. When I run my coding it doesn't connect to the database which I don't know how to compare the user input with the database value.

```
import pymysql,time

def login():
    db = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',user='root',password='',db='ghost')
    cursor = db.cursor()

    while True:
        usercode = input("please enter your usercode: ")
        password = input("please enter your password: ")

        find_user = ("SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE usercode ='$usercode' AND password = '$password'")
        cursor.execute(find_user)
        results = cursor.fetchall()

        if results:
            for i in results:
                print("SUCCESS "+i[2])
            #return("exit")
            break

        else:
            print("usercode and password not recognised")
            again = input("Do you want to try again?(y/n): ")
            if again.lower() == "n":
                print("Goodbye")
                time.sleep(1)
                #return("exit")
                break
login()
```

and for your information I use sublime text 3. When I run the code at cmd

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Dell Inspiron Mini>D:

D:\>xampp\htdocs\T1.py
please enter your usercode: 7803069
please enter your password: 3069
usercode and password not recognised
Do you want to try again?(y/n):
```

I already put the correct usercode and password which already have in the database.
I hope u can help me

Comment: ``it doesn't connect to the database`` if you get an error message, please add it to your question above. You could also try to connect with any other DB manager to your DB with the same credentials to make sure it's not an issue of username/password/db.

Comment: I add the cmd result on the question. I dont know how to connect with the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`` "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE usercode ='$usercode' AND password = '$password'" `` will literally search the DB for `$usercode` and `$password`. You will need to substitute those values.

Ideally, by using SQL bindings / parameterized queries.

**Example:**

```
    usercode = input("please enter your usercode: ")
    password = input("please enter your password: ")

    sql = "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE usercode = %s AND password = %s"
    cursor.execute(sql, (usercode, password))
```

More examples can be found on the PyMySQL github page: https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL

---

If you don't want to use bindings, you could also build the statement yourself by formatting it.

Note: in productive environments this is a security risk, bindings are the preferred way to do this and the following example is really just to show an alternative.

```
    usercode = input("please enter your usercode: ")
    password = input("please enter your password: ")

    sql = "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE usercode='{}' AND password='{}'".format(usercode, password)
    cursor.execute(sql)
```

Comment: I already change that. Then I run again the program but still have the error

Comment: No, please don't recommend formatting a query string "manually". This should always be done via bindings.

Comment: this is the error.....

C:\Users\Dell Inspiron Mini>D:

D:\>xampp\htdocs\T1.py
please enter your usercode: 7803069
please enter your password: 3069
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\xampp\htdocs\T1.py", line 29, in <module>
    login()
  File "D:\xampp\htdocs\T1.py", line 17, in login
    print("SUCCESS "+i[2])
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Comment: @SyameezaNatasha  ``print("SUCCESS "+str(i[2]))`` - again, this could be done nicer by using ``format`` as it will take care of type conversions for you.

Comment: @SyameezaNatasha Please read the error information you just posted. It tells you exactly where and what the problem is. You try to concatenate the string SUCCESS and an integer from your result in `i[2]` using the + operator.

Comment: @shmee indeed, bindings are to be preferred. I added a note to my answer.